# Issue On OpenGLRenderer : Path Too Large To Be Rendered To a Texture

Tags: android, canvas, opengl-es, hardware-acceleration

i have a `TextView` inside of a `ReleativeLayout` which i set a big Text into that at runtime.
the problem is about my `ReleativeLayout` background which is a rounded shape with a border. it doesn't set the background and in Logcat it says that :

```
12-12 16:26:56.602: W/OpenGLRenderer(7400): Path too large to be rendered into a texture
```

i've solved this issue by turning **android:hardwareAccelerated** to false in manifest file(one activity not whole application) , but it raise another error when i use sliding menu inside my Activity which it tells that :

```
12-12 16:37:05.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9520): java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@4633e3f8
```

i have just a ListView without any bitmap inside of my SlidingMenu which is 6Wunderkinder SlidingLayer library.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally solved it with just changing LayerType of my Fragment ScrollView from HardwareAcceleration to Software without setting HardwareAcceleration false for whole Activity which caused strange bahavior as mentioned on SlidingMenu :

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layerType="software">
```

Comment: This is not exactly solving the problem. Answer is not taking into account possible performance consequences.

Comment: If anything, I saw improved performance with a software layerType -- presumably disabling hardware texture rendering had no adverse effects on the half-dozen low- and high-end devices I tested.

Comment: Been stuck converting our 2009 app to the Target 26. All graphics went slug. Fixed it in a pinch!

Answer (score 5):

This happens to me when i have a scrollview that is too long with a drawable in the rootview, this effects every device uniquely. My Nexus 9 will show most anything but my sony compact won't.  It is not worth it to turn hardware acceleration off because on low end devices you will probably have a very choppy application.

In this situation you should probably consider using a listview or recyclerview instead to ensure your background element is not larger than the screen. Even XML drawables in the background of a not so long scrollview will create this error. I choose for safety and would redesign elements, simplu removing the background from the scrollview could be an options , and placing them as tiles in the inner elements.

It is seems strange but it must have to do with how the background is rendered by that rootview in a longer scrollview, because a scrollview itself can be quite long, with many complex elements without an issues, and background colors are as well never a problem..

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it programmatically you can set:

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```